# Creating objects as global / static object crashes, while a local object doesn't

Tags: c++

I created a class for OpenGL textures and for some applications, a static object would be useful. 
The problem is, when I create a texture as static or global object, my program crashes, while as local object, everything works fine. I have absolutely no idea what is going on.

This is my constructor:

```
Texture::Texture(std::string file, bool bitmap):
textureName("tex"), transparent(false) {
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    int texWidth, texHeight;

    unsigned char *data = SOIL_load_image(file.c_str(), &texWidth, &texHeight, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    if(bitmap) {
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else {
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    for(int i = 3; i < texWidth * texHeight * 4; i+= 4) {
        if(data[i] != 0xff) {
            transparent = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    textureSize = glm::vec2(texWidth, texHeight);

    SOIL_free_image_data(data);
}
```

Comment: Presumably some kind of static initialization order fiasco. If `SOIL` or OpenGL needs to perform some kind of static initialization before working properly, then you might make a mess with calling all these functions in your own static initialization (which might happen before that). There are several options between "static initialization" and "local object" though. What happens if you initialize all this _after_ `main` has been entered?

Comment: Or is there even something like a StartOpenGL() call you have to make, usually in main? Statics are initialised before main is called (that is the only guarantee)

Comment: @MaxLanghof That could be a problem, SOIL doesn't have an init function, but OpenGL. As I said, if I use the variable as local, everything works, when used after the OpenGL inits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL must be initialized before you can call any OpenGL functions. (More accurately: you need to have "made an OpenGL context current")

The way you do that depends on which libraries you are using.

One thing that all the libraries have in common is: there are some functions you need to call, which you usually call in `main`. (for example, `glfwCreateWindow` and `glfwMakeContextCurrent` in GLFW)

Since global objects are created before `main` is called, you are trying to call OpenGL functions before you have an OpenGL context. This doesn't work.

Comment: This seems to be the right track, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user11914177 create the objects after initializing OpenGL - either don't make them global variables, or don't create the OpenGL textures yet in the constructor of `Texture`.